# Java's Swing changing size of layout regious with mouse

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I have a JFrame with a BoxLayout divided into 2 columns. Ideally I would like it so when the mouse hovers over the dividing line, I could click and drag that line to dynamically change the sizing of the layout. Is there a tool or better way to do that?

Comment: Check out JSplitPane: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html

Comment: Start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above, use JSplitPane. See example below

```
public class SplitPaneDemo extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new SplitPaneDemo());
    }

    SplitPaneDemo() {
        super("SplitPaneDemo");

        JLabel lhs = new JLabel("LHS");
        lhs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 200));

        JLabel rhs = new JLabel("RHS");
        rhs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 200));

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true); // Update window as splitter is moved
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(lhs);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(rhs);

        setContentPane(splitPane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [JSplitPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) as your `contentPane` of `jFrame` is the better way.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for! Very simple to use.